# Is Prices law a consequence of Benford's law?

Tags: power-law

**Background**
Price's law says this:
In an company, half of all value is created by the square root of the people.

I'm sure Dr. Price looked at more than the median, but I suspect this was how the technically-illiterate average person could ingest the rule.

Benford's law (reduced) says this:
For many sets of real world numbers the first digit is 1 about 30% of the time.

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benford%27s_law) Benford's law applies to: *"...electricity bills, street addresses, stock prices, house prices, population numbers, death rates, lengths of rivers, and physical and mathematical constants"*

This prevalence is related to power-laws underlying a wide variety of natural phenomena.

**Question:**
So can Prices value-creation law be derived from a Benford-like premise?

Or, restated, does the power-law behind Benford's law speak to the mechanisms driving Price's law?

Comment: Benford's Law is not necessarily related to power laws: it applies to almost any distribution whose support covers orders of magnitude.  It is difficult to see how such a general phenomenon could be used to deduce such a specialized statement as Price's Law.